# Mysql отсеивание результатов с нулевыми значениями в конец выборки при сортировке по возрастанию.

Tags: mysql

Простейший пример для моего вопроса: товары, цена которых задана как 0. Во многих движках это равнозначно "нет в продаже". Хотелось бы одним запросом запихать такие записи в конец выборки.

На ум приходит способ с двумя запросами

```
`price`>0...
`price`=0
```

Является ли это наиболее эффективным?

P.S.offtop:
Может, вообще отказаться от порочной практики нулевой цены?

Comment: price >= 0

Comment: откажышь, проапдейть таблицу, зачем тебе разные значения одной цены?

Comment: Затем что если пользователь забывает вбить цену, либо сознательно ее ставит 0.
price>=0 не пойдет, так как тогда при сортировке по возрастанию первыми будут не самые дешевые вещи, а самые по-идиотски заполненные.

Comment: так сделай фильтр, сделай обязательные поя для заполнения, поставь условия перед записью в бд, если null, то записть 0

Comment: Вообще, вешать на цену какую-то дополнительную семантику - плохая практика. продажа по нулевой цене - это подарки, именно с нулевой ценой, которые в основном прайсе не показываются.
Для невозможности непосредственного заказа есть разные причины:

 - хз какая цена, звоните, шеф скажет какой курс на седня, мы помножим.
 - хз какая цена, будем у поставщиков из-за бугра заказывать, может $100
 - нет и не будет, но было, взамен может что-то другое предложить (например, из маркета приходят по нему часто)
 - и т.д.

Я голосую за отдельный статус товара (как вариант 0 количество).

Comment: ORDER BY CASE WHEN price = 0 THEN <верхняя граница типа поля price> ELSE price END
(=

Answer (score 2, accepted):

При данной сортировке, в начале отсортирует цены от меньшей к большей, а в конце те, что равны "0"

```
SELECT `price`
FROM `products`
ORDER BY IF( `price` = 0, 1, 0 ) , `price`
```

Это что касается запроса, а про нужность нулевой цены, вам господа коллеги всё рассказали. И лично я поддерживаю то, что сказал [[@Yura Ivanov](/users/6117/yura-ivanov)](/users/6117/yura-ivanov)

Comment: можно написать кратко: 
ORDER BY `price` = 0, `price`